# Firebase - Change data before being sent from cache to server

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase for my chat application I am developing with Swift. I have offline persistence enabled, so normally each query is first cached and then sent to the server. What I want to do is, when sending a message, have the message status first set to "Sending" and the time to current time, but when the data is sent to the server, change the status to "Sent" and the time to when the data was sent (because it could be minutes to whatever if there's slow connection or no connection at all). Is this possible using Firebase? If not, any workarounds? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firebase has two databases: Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore. Which one are you using?

Comment: Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Firestore you can detect the status of your write operations by:

1. attaching a completion listener to the write operation
2. looking at the metadata of document snapshots

For the first step, have a look at the example of [writing a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) in the documentation. The completion listener there allows you to detect when the write operation is completed.

But if you want to show in the UI for each document you show whether it has pending writes that have not yet been committed on the server, you might be better off looking at the metadata of each document snapshot. As explained in the documentation in [events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes). While the changes are pending, the `snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()` will return true. Then once the changes are committed on the server, it will return `false` again.